# Replace nan in column with the mean between two values python dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as below. There are values for the speed with an indeterminate amount of nan values between the two values. I am trying to replace the nan values with the mean between the two numeric values.

```
timestamp   ...           Speed km h^-1
0     1434838676097.07006835937500000000  ... 53.02799834399999667767
1     1434838676130.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
2     1434838676229.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
3     1434838676328.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
4     1434838676429.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
5     1434838676526.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
6     1434838676625.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
7     1434838676726.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
8     1434838676826.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
9     1434838676924.07006835937500000000  ...                     nan
10    1434838676992.07006835937500000000  ... 51.19200097200000243447
```

Comment: can you please repost the data in a way that we can copy it into our IDE

Comment: I think that just takes the average of the whole column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply use [pandas.Series.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

So here, since you want to fill the nan values with the average of the filled values above and below them it should look like:

```
df.Speed.interpolate()
```

This will return a series of all the speed measures and an interpolation for nan values.